# messages between local Silverlight apps without using local messaging

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, https, messaging

I have one silverlight application hosted in HTTPS and another in HTTP. How can I send messages between them? Silverlight's local messaging system can not send messages between silverlight apps hosted in different URI scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight's local messaging system typicaly uses for communication silverlight plugins on the same page. So, you provide more complex scenario. You access to first via https and to second via http, as I understant each application hosted in an own page and you want provide communication between this application. I think you should use services to synchronize their on server.